# How to force NestJS not to start on the type-check error?

Tags: nestjs, swc-compiler

Recently I switch from `tsc` to `swc` compiler in my NestJS app. I have a problem with `start:dev` command. With `tsc` if in the code were some type errors app didn't start and it was ok because, on the bottom of the console, I had a list of errors.

Now, with the `swc` if I have some type error, files compile, app is starting and running. All errors are on the top of the console, sometimes they are not visible.

Do you know how to stop `swc` to not compile code with type check errors or how to stop the NestJS app to not start with errors? It happens only in `dev/watch` mode, in `start` mode it works as it should.

I tried to find any option in the NestJS and `swc` configuration, but now I'm out of ideas how I can manage this.

My NestJS and swc configuration are the same as provided by the NestjS migration guide.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same problem..